# How to instantiate prefab with perfect size in ScrollView at unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I have some problems with element positioning at unity3d. I try to put data in table rows like this(on FreeAcpect screen). And It's look good. But on wide screen table rows are look narrow.
Table row is a prefab. 
How to make rows responsive?
[image]
[image: 3d]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here, seems to me like a UI layout problem, most likely with anchoring the objects themselves. Without seeing your scene view and hiearchy I can't tell you the exact solution, but I believe that if you take a look at the [Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html) about UI layout, you can solve this issue with ease.

Answer (score 0):

The extention from asset store(FREE) easy going [TSTableView](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/tstableview-27615).

[image]

[image]